Getting Error while doing integration for AgenticRAG and Crew-Ai for llms
While using Agentic RAG with Crew-Ai and using their own integrated tools such as pdfTool or TXTSearchTool, I am getting the following error: "
ImportError: cannot import name 'PydanticDeprecationWarning' from 'pydantic' (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AgentRAGsearch\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic_init_.cp310-win_amd64.pyd)"

I attempted to implement a selecting route to add our own local ollama instead of langchainOpenAi, but it did not work. I also attempted to downgrade the V2 version of Pydentic to V1, as I had seen many people get stuck because of it. I also attempted some manual integration in site packages in the libs folder, but it did not work for me either.
